# HTML5/JS How to create an autocompleted tag input like StackOverflow Tags field

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, html-input

I want to create an input for tags/labels/flags etc. similar to the one shown at: https://gitignore.io.

I found similar questions using jQuery UI Plugins, but I am searching for a very lightweight solution. (I want to use this with Phoenix and Bootstrap 3).

Related questions I've found (I find it hard to google for this since both tag and label already have a meaning in html):

- [How can I create an autocomplete box for the tag input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39605541)
- [jQuery autocomplete tagging plug-in like StackOverflow's input tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107) (Essentially the tag-it plugin is what I am searching for, except that it requires jQuery UI)

Answer (score 0):

I've found this link, which seems promising: http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/

I can be found also on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/magicsuggest

Comment: It seems to work only with jQuery version 1.x...